# need a Selenium guide for radio button not able to clicking

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm having trouble clicking a radio button using Java Selenium and JUnit.

While the syntax appears correct and the button is located, but I'm still getting an exception which is this :

```
org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element <input type="radio" id="yesRadio" name="like" class="custom-control-input"> is not clickable at point (333, 534). Other element would receive the click: <iframe frameborder="0" src="[https://be82b301cd639377a83c1cc02b250d58.safeframe.googlesyndication.com/safeframe/1-0-40/html/container.html](https://be82b301cd639377a83c1cc02b250d58.safeframe.googlesyndication.com/safeframe/1-0-40/html/container.html)" id="google\_ads\_iframe\_/21849154601,22343295815/Ad.Plus-Anchor\_0" title="3rd party ad content" name="" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" width="728" height="90" data-is-safeframe="true" sandbox="allow-forms allow-popups allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation" aria-label="Advertisement" tabindex="0" data-google-container-id="1" style="border: 0px; vertical-align: bottom;" data-load-complete="true"></iframe>
```

This is the entire code :

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver;

public class Assign2 {
    WebDriver driver;
    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp(){
        driver= new EdgeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.navigate().to("https://demoqa.com/radio-button");
    }
    @Test
    public void radioChecker(){
        By radio1 = By.id("yesRadio");
        driver.findElement(radio1).click();
        boolean isSelect1 = driver.findElement(radio1).isSelected();
        Assertions.assertTrue(isSelect1);
    }
    @AfterEach
    public void quitTap(){
        driver.quit();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve it by employing the **XPath** of the "label" for clicking and utilized the "input" for assertion. Consequently, the code appears as follows:

````
    public void checkingOptions(String optionName){
        By radioButtonSelector1= By.xpath("//*[@for='yesRadio']");
        driver.findElement(radioButtonSelector1).click();
        //Verify whether all 3 options given to the question can be selected.
        boolean isRadioSelected = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='yesRadio']")).isSelected();
        Assertions.assertTrue(isRadioSelected);
        //When each option is selected, print the following texts on the console.
        String radioBtnTxt= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='text-success']")).getText();
        System.out.println("You have selected "+radioBtnTxt); ```
````

Answer (score 2):

Error is happened, as far as input with id `yesButton` is overlapped by another element and element that is placed forward receives a click.

To avoid this, you just need to click on element that represents your radio button and actually is clickable.

Example - label with css selector `[for=yesRadio]`

```java
driver.get("https://demoqa.com/radio-button");
By radioButtonSelector = By.cssSelector("[for=yesRadio]");
driver.findElement(radioButtonSelector).click();
boolean isRadioSelected = driver.findElement(By.id("yesRadio")).isSelected();
Assertions.assertTrue(isRadioSelected);
```

Answer (score 0):

The selenium/webdriver error *element `Action` intercepted:* is thrown by Selenium when there is another HTML element overlaying the element you are trying to `Action` (in your case, 'click'.

Selenium is throwing this error because if a *human* user attempted to perform that click, it wouldn't work as the other element (the iframe) would receive the `Action` event.

In the error, Selenium shows the element that would have got the `Action` (your 'click' action.).  In your case it is an iframe element;

```
    <iframe frameborder="0" src="[https://be82b301cd639377a83c1cc02b250d58.safeframe.googlesyndication.com/safeframe/1-0-40/html/container.html](https://be82b301cd639377a83c1cc02b250d58.safeframe.googlesyndication.com/safeframe/1-0-40/html/container.html)" id="google\_ads\_iframe\_/21849154601,22343295815/Ad.Plus-Anchor\_0" title="3rd party ad content" name="" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" width="728" height="90" data-is-safeframe="true" sandbox="allow-forms allow-popups allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation" aria-label="Advertisement" tabindex="0" data-google-container-id="1" style="border: 0px; vertical-align: bottom;" data-load-complete="true"></iframe>
```

Easiest way to resolve this is to use the z-index (along with a position). See [How to overlay an iframe and allow click through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41418413/how-to-overlay-an-iframe-and-allow-click-through) for a good description of how to do this; @NeriBarakat's answer is probably the best.

Comment: While that link describes the problem well, the solution is from the perspective of the webdev, not the Selenium script writer.